# Meaning of のか in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles, questions, sentence, explanatory-の

The sentence is this one:

> その音に反応したのか、わたしの耳に一つの声が届いた

I kinda understand the connotation that のか has in some sentences, but I just don't understand it in this particular one.

Answer (score 2):

In this sentence, のか means that the speaker is guessing at a cause.  To translate the sentence, "Perhaps reacting to the sound, I heard a voice."  Kind of a gross translation, but essentially the speaker is guessing that the voice they hear is from someone vocalizing in reaction to the referenced sound.

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t know whether or not whatever uttered the voice did so in response to the sound, you might say:

> その音に反応した**のか**どうかわからない。

If you suspect it did, you might say:

> その音に反応した**のかも**しれない。

のか in your sentence should be understood along these lines.

In fact, he could have as well said:

> その音に反応したのかもしれない。わたしの耳に一つの声が届いた。

or

> その音に反応したのかもしれないが、わたしの耳に一つの声が届いた。

You wouldn’t be terribly mistaken if you thought of その音に反応したのか as a shorter conjunctional form of this.

---

**[EDIT]**
Maybe I should add that this conjunction is a causal one, although the speaker is not completely sure about the cause.